# Shared instance not being set properly

Tags: ios, objective-c

So my shared instance object keeps returning nil.

**ViewController.h**

I have a property
`@property (nonatomic) BOOL isConnected;`

**ViewController.m**

```
@interface ViewController () {
    BOOL _isConnected;
}
@synthesize isConnected = _isConnected;


-(void)bleDidConnectPeripheral : (CBPeripheral *)aPeripheral{
     _isConnected = TRUE;
}
```

I know bleDidConnect is being called since I logged it.

**ViewControllerTwo.m**

```
NSLog([[ViewController sharedInstance] isConnected] ? @"TRUE" : @"FALSE");
```

*Keeps returning false, unless I set _isConnected = TRUE in the init of ViewController.m*

Comment: Does `[ViewController sharedInstance]` return a non-nil value?

Comment: It seems you deleted your previous and related question for some reason. The code you posted is not for a singleton. Show more relevant code in your question.

Comment: you should never, ever, EVER make your view controllers a singleton

Comment: BTW - you seem to following a really old and outdate tutorial. There is no need for the ivar and the `@synthesize` line. Find yourself a modern tutorial.

Comment: I think there is a fundamental lack of understanding here about the difference between a _class_ and an _instance of a class_

Comment: @i_am_jorf yes it returns a value

Comment: One way to debug this is to implement `-(void)setIsConnected(BOOL)` and set a breakpoint inside it to see when and if it actually gets set or changes.

Comment: @rmaddy I just wanted it to be more clear of what I was doing because it was confusing

Comment: @i_am_jorf `- (void)setIsConnected:(BOOL)isConnected` is not called.

Comment: I'd argue "never make your view controller a singleton unless you _really_ know what you're doing". In this case, it is unclear why @user3281743 wants to use a singleton pattern. Post more code, and answer: how do you initialize the shared instance? where do you register for the bluetooth notifications? why are you declaring ivars and using @synthesize? Post all of the code you have.

Comment: @Nick Why does it matter if I register the bluetooth notifications. Like I said the function is clearly being called. We know that the shared instance is being initialized because it's not returning null.

Comment: You are not making this easy for anyone to help since you refuse to post relevant code. Is `bleDidConnectPeripheral` being called on the shared instance or some other instance of `ViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the comments. I feel that you are getting a lot of things mixed up and confused. (this is why I despise stackoverflow because people just ctrl + c & ctrl + p, but the bashing doesn't do any good either)

Looking from your code to `_isConnected = TRUE` is being set inside that class, but when you try to access it outside it is being set `False`

Try this replace `_isConnected` with `[ViewController sharedInstance].isConnected = TRUE`

And try calling it in your other class.

Hopefully you can learn why this works and the other way doesn't. Really try to understand what is going on! That is the beauty of coding.

Comment: It's bad advice to suggest that the `bleDidConnectPeripheral` method be updated to update the shared instance instead of "self".